# render a child component afterViewInit in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

```js
    <ng-container *ngIf="isTrue; else notTrue">
      <app-child
        [property1]="value"
        [property2]="value"
        [property3]="value"
        (function1)="func($event)"
      ></app-child>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-template #notTrue>
     <app-child
        [property1]="value"
        [property2]="value"
        (function1)="func($event)"
      ></app-child>
    </ng-template>
```

I want to initialize and render the child component wrapped in `<ng-template #notTrue>` after parent's `afterViewInit()` hook.
How to do that?

PS I'm using Angular 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your parent component for this template you could implement AfterViewInit and set isTrue = true like so:

```
export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    isTrue: boolean;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.isTrue = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you do, you should do the logic to determine your *ngIf's in ngAfterViewInit if you want it to happen at that point in the lifecycle.

This will still cause your ng-template to render before the ngAfterViewInit triggers the switch, however. If you don't want anything to render till after the view is init (say your inputs aren't defined and it's breaking the child component's ngOnInit logic or something) then you could always throw another boolean into the class and set it to true on ngAfterViewInit(). Then, wrap both things inside of a

```
<ng-container *ngIf="viewHasInitialized">
...app-child components...
</ng-container>
```